# #import with defined prefix (possibly the product name)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can I import a file with a pre-defined prefix.

e.g. something like this (pseudo code)

`#import PRODUCT_NAME+"-Config.h"`

I want to have different targets in Xcode for my application. Each target can have its own configuration file(s). I want this to be automatic however, so if the `PRODUCT_NAME` bit can be the actual target product name that would be the best way.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you tried with no success or some issues please inform us.

Comment: Well... my foray into guessing how to do this returned this: 1. You can't concatenate preprocessor statements with a `+`. 2. Concatenation with a `##` also doesn't seem to work. `#import CONST ## "-Config.h"` returns `Expected Filename`. 3. I have no idea how to get the product name at pre-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Setup each target with a unique flag under the `Other C Flags` build setting. Then you can do something like:

```
#if defined(TARGET1)
    #import "Target1Config.h"
#elif defined(TARGET2)
    #import "Target2Config.h"
#endif
```

where `TARGET1` and `TARGET2` are each defined only for the corresponding target's build settings.

Comment: This is a good answer and was/is my backup plan. But what I really want to be able to do is just let it run itself. Create a new target, change the product name and create the new config. I'd rather not have to do this extra step if I don't have to. :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson If you create a new target then you are likely to be using a new source directory, yes?  Therefore just create a `Config.h` file within that target source directory and it will work.  **EDIT** I see Amy Worrall has already suggested this to you, but you will find it too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the config files the exact same name, but locate them in different folders. Make sure that each config file only has the appropriate target ticked. Then you can just do `#import "Config.h"`, and the relevant Config.h will be used each time.

Comment: Good idea, but this sounds quite complicated for maintenance, especially as XCode does absolutely nothing to help you maintain IRL folder structures.

Comment: I don't find it too bad. I make an Xcode group that maps to each RL folder (select the group in Xcode, then in the first tab on the sidebar, give it a path "Relative to Group" by clicking the little white square icon).

Comment: Hmm well in that case this may very well be the way I do it then! Seeing as there doesn't seem to be a better option, and it actually might help putting each targets specific files in its own folder. Thanks for the suggestion.